# Hot Spots is missing from dotCover Unit Tests Coverage in Rider

Tags: plugins, jetbrains-ide, rider, dotcover

I've installed the dotCover plugin in Jetbrains Rider but Hot Spots is missing from the Unit Test Coverage menu in Rider and I don't have the Coverage Tree either. Anyone know why?

This is what I'm supposed to see:

[image: This is what I'm supposed to see]

This is what I have:

[image: This is what I have]

Comment: So if you're not seeing any coverage information at all, probably your config is wrong. You'd have to share your test project

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the Hot Spots functionality doesn't yet exist in Rider. However it is on their radar and a feature request exists for it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-17833/Add-Hot-spots-view